# How to add Tree in the Combo box

Tags: extjs

We are trying to show the tree structure in the combo box using the following source
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g50&view/editor

We are able to view the tree structure in the combo box however when we select any node its not being displayed in the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a treepicker component available in [ExtJS 4](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker) and [ExtJS 6](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.ux.TreePicker.html). From the fiddle you have provided, I can see that you use ExtJS version 5, but I could not find any reference to the treepicker in the API Docs for this version. You can sneak peek into the version 4 and 6 implementation.

But basically, you just missed setting an event listener on the tree panel picker that will update the value of the field: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qt0&view/editor

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to set the value in the combo box now. I have another question the combo box allowing me to select the root element also. how can we prevent from selecting the root elements?

Comment: I guess by roots you mean non-leaf elements (elements with no children). In this case, you should add an additional check in the `onItemClick` method: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qtr&view/editor